# Typedef Struct of itself in C

Tags: c, struct

How can I make this to work ?

```c
typedef struct {
    A_t* obj;
} A_t;
```

A_t is unknown. But pointer (fixed size). Can I do it without using void* ?

Answer (score -2):

Ok I find

```c
typedef struct A_t A_t;
struct A_t {
    A_t* obj;
};
```